# Integral representation of $\mathrm{Cl}_{2n}(x)$

Tags: improper-integrals

Out of curiosity: Is there a nice integral representation of [Clausen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function) of order $2n$? $\mathrm{Cl}_{2n}(x)$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I think it's only for $\mathrm{Cl}_2(x)$?

Comment: $\operatorname{Cl}_{2n}(x)$ is a polylogarithm in disguise, with many known integral representations. Say, $$\operatorname{Cl}_{2n}(x)=\frac{\sin x}{2(2n-1)!}\int_0^\infty\frac{y^{2n-1}\,dy}{\cosh y-\cos x}.$$

Comment: @metamorphy Can you please tell sources for it's integral representations?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Integral_representations) and the links out there.

Comment: @metamorphy Any idea for $\mathrm{Cl}_{2n+1}(x)$?

Comment: $$\operatorname{Cl}_{2n+1}(x)=\frac1{2(2n)!}\int_0^\infty y^{2n}\frac{\cos x-e^{-y}}{\cosh y-\cos x}\,dy$$ is obtained the same way as for $\operatorname{Cl}_{2n}(x)$.