# Closed form of $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{y^{2n-1}\,dy}{\cosh y - \cos(z + \pi)}$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I'm looking for a nice closed form of the below integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{y^{2n-1}\,dy}{\cosh y - \cos(z + \pi)}$$

I'm stuck on this for quite some time, I have tried contour integration and integrating by parts and that doesn't seem to get me anywhere. Your insight would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the $\cos(z+\pi)$ supposed to be like that?

Comment: @NinadMunshi um Yeah?

Comment: What I mean is is it supposed to be a constant or is it supposed to be $\cos(y+\pi)$? Please offer more details than "um Yeah"

Comment: While sparse OP's post does not deserve to be downvoted, it is an nonduplicate with vague explanations of where OP went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The integral appears in my comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4114424). For $|r|<1$ we have $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty r^k\sin kx=\Im\frac1{1-re^{ix}}=\frac{r\sin x}{1-2r\cos x+r^2},$$ so that, if we put $r=e^{-y}$, multiply by $y^{2n-1}$ and integrate, we get $$\frac{\sin x}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{y^{2n-1}\,dy}{\cosh y-\cos x}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sin kx\int_0^\infty y^{2n-1}e^{-ky}\,dy=(2n-1)!\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin kx}{k^{2n}},$$ resulting in Clausen functions. (Put $x=z+\pi$.)

Comment: so you mean my integral equals $(2n-1)!\,\mathrm{Cl}_{2n}(z+\pi)$?

Comment: @BooleanWick: ... multiplied by $2/\sin(z+\pi)=-2/\sin z$.